# compare array of json object in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

I have two array which is holding json object is there is any way to compare these two array if yes please reply.

```
"initial": [

  {
       "level1":10000,
       "level2":20000,
       "increment1":5000,
       "increment2":5000
  },
  {
       "level1":20000,
       "level2":40000,
       "increment1":5000,
       "increment2":6000
  },
  {
       "level1":30000,
       "level2":40000,
       "increment1":10000,
       "increment2":10000
  }

]


"after": [

  {
       "level1":10000,
       "level2":20000,
       "increment1":5000,
       "increment2":5000
  },
  {
       "level1":20000,
       "level2":40000,
       "increment1":5000,
       "increment2":6000
  },
  {
       "level1":20000,
       "level2":50000,
       "increment1":100,
       "increment2":500
  }

]
```

you can see from above sample in after array the last object is different.

Comment: do you mean check if they are the same (same values) ?

Comment: I don't think your question is related to JSON.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript